# are set of strings all substrings of another set

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have many sets of strings and wish to test them against sets of substrings. I wish to identify which sets contain all of the substrings.

```
set1 = {'A123', 'B234', 'C345'}
set2 = {'A123', 'F234', 'H345'}
substring_set1 = {'A', 'B'}
```

So something like this in pseudocode:

```
all(substring_set1.areSubstrings(set1))
True

all(substring_set1.areSubstrings(set2)
False
```

Or something like this maybe?

```
if all(x in v for v in set1 for x in substring_set1):
    do stuff
```

I guess I could go about it with an array of for loops, but I feel there probably is a cleaner way of doing this. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why your approach with `all` doesn't work? Should the result be `True` rather than `False`?

Comment: How big are these sets? The naive approach will work for smallish sets of strings, but will become inefficient for bigger ones since it takes O(N^2) time (you end up comparing every string with all elements of the set).  An efficient solution to this problem is to use suffix trees or suffix arrays, but these data structures are quite complex to implement. You may find some library that provides them.

Answer (score 3):

The following approach looks clean enough to me:

```
>>> all(any(x in v for v in set1) for x in substring_set1)
True
>>> all(any(x in v for v in set2) for x in substring_set1)
False
```